# Dealing with 302 Redirection in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, redirect, http-status-code-302

I am using FFMPEG Library to Stream Audio from RTSP URL. My Sample Streaming URL is:

```
rtsp://username:password@machine-ip/708314c4eba2a041
```

And I am using the following command for streaming this RTSP URL:

```
ffmpeg -i RTSP_URL -f mov C:\FFMPEG_Recordings\bay.mov
```

So, the above FFMPEG command will capture the media stream from RTSP_URL and will store in bay.mov media file.

Sometimes, I get 302 Redirection Error from the Server which is actually propagating streams. Such as:

```
[rtsp @ 0000000002cc8100] Status 302: Redirecting to rtsp://server-ip:server-port/708314c4eba2a041?token=708114c4e99dbcd1^LA^0^0^0^1427248150^e77149b2a2c209982a74367d0f72c2e11ba6636c
```

And after this process gets stuck (on Command Prompt) until I press CTRL+C twicely to terminate it in cmd where I run this command.

While It should start streaming from the redirected URL automatically.

I read that It's a FFMPEG's bug on [FFMPEG Track](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3973) and also read about it on  [FFMPEG Discussion Community](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2012-April/122753.html) but didn't get any solution or workaround for this.

Please guide to overcome this scenario If anyone ever encountered it that what are workarounds for this. Thnaks

Comment: What FFmpeg version are you using? Try with the git snapshot and see if you can reproduce it.

Comment: I'm using Version 2.5.3